# How to read an audio file in an array format from libsndfile library like MATLAB's audioread

Tags: c++, matlab, audio, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I am using libsndfile to read .caf file. I am able to read the file properly with number of items in the audio file. However, when I save those numbers in a text file and try to verify my values with MATLAB, they look a lot different. I have attached the code in C++ and the values I obtain from C++ and MATLAB.

```
void ofApp::setup(){


const char* fn = "/Users/faiyadhshahid/Desktop/Desktopdemo.caf";

SNDFILE *sf;
SF_INFO info;
int num_channels, num, num_items, *buf, f, sr,c, i , j;
FILE *out;

/* Open the WAV file. */
info.format = 0;
sf = sf_open(fn,SFM_READ,&info);
if (sf == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
}

/* Print some of the info, and figure out how much data to read. */
f = info.frames;
sr = info.samplerate;
c = info.channels;
printf("frames=%d\n",f);
printf("samplerate=%d\n",sr);
printf("channels=%d\n",c);
num_items = f*c;
printf("num_items=%d\n",num_items);

/* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
buf = (int *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));
num = sf_read_int(sf,buf,num_items);
sf_close(sf);
printf("Read %d items\n",num);
/* Write the data to filedata.out. */
out = fopen("/Users/faiyadhshahid/Desktop/filedata.txt","w");
for (i = 0; i < num; i += c)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        fprintf(out,"%d ",buf[i+j]);
    fprintf(out,"\n");
}
fclose(out);
return 0;
```

}

[Values of C++ (on left)  vs MATLAB (on right):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eih2D.jpg)

Comment: Note how in matlab you have a very small number. 0.00021.... No way that's an `int`, so why compare with an `int`? Looks like you've a bit of work ahead getting both data sets into the same units.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. I was comparing apples with oranges. 
The changes I needed to make were to convert the buffer saving the values to read float values. `int num_channels, num, num_items,f, sr,c, i , j;
    float *buf;
    FILE *out;

```
/* Open the WAV file. */
info.format = 0;
sf = sf_open(fn,SFM_READ,&info);
if (sf == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
}

/* Print some of the info, and figure out how much data to read. */
f = info.frames;
sr = info.samplerate;
c = info.channels;
printf("frames=%d\n",f);
printf("samplerate=%d\n",sr);
printf("channels=%d\n",c);
num_items = f*c;
printf("num_items=%d\n",num_items);

/* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
buf = (float *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(float));
num = sf_read_float(sf,buf,num_items);
sf_close(sf);
printf("Read %d items\n",num);
/* Write the data to filedata.out. */
out = fopen("/Users/faiyadhshahid/Desktop/filedata.txt","w");
for (i = 0; i < num; i += c)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
         fprintf(out,"%f \n",buf[i]);
            // fprintf(out,"\n");
}
fclose(out);
```

`

Comment: Gotta say that was simpler than I expected. I figured it would be something more like read in, then apply y=mx+b